# How can I add more classes in C# Windows Forms project?

Tags: c#

When you program in Java, you have a package, and in that package you put class files, where you write your logic, you have one main file, and you spread your code in the rest of the classes, for example, I have one class which I use only for static variables, like this:

```
package com.mypackage.models;

public class MyConsts {

    public static final boolean DEBUG = true;
    // bla bla bla
}
```

and then, from whichever class I can call that variable like this

```
MyConsts.DEBUG
```

Now, how do you make more classes just like in Java, but in C# for a Windows Forms application, currently I only have this, and I only write the code in `Form1.cs`:

[image]

Comment: 1. That's not WPF, more like Windows Forms. 2. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287565%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: but how do I reference variables from that class inside my Form1.cs?

Comment: If you put your MyConsts class in a different file, you can still get to it from your classes in Form1.cs. In C# the decision of which classes to place in which files is up to the programmer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about elementary IDE behavior, not programming topics.

Comment: @Telastyn where should I ask such questions then?

Comment: @SartherisStormhammer - you can figure it out without asking? I mean it's the _same_ ***exact*** thing as in any Java IDE. It is step one of any tutorial. It is the standard way as creating a new file in any windows application known to man. I'm sorry to be harsh, but there are uncountable problems you'll face as a programmer. If you have to ask people about all of them, you'll never get anywhere.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-split-a-class-into-partial-classes?view=vs-2019

Comment: lol .. I didn't notice it was 5 years ago. I think you are a pro coder now :v .. That link has the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add more classes, just create additional files. You may have noticed that you have not one, but two classes: `Form1` and `Program`: the last one corresponds to the `Program.cs` at the bottom on your screenshot.

In order to use those additional classes from your form:

- Either initialize an instance of the class within the form. If it shares the same namespace than your form class, you can do it by name. Otherwise, you'll have to import the namespace with `using` statement.
- Or call the static members of the class directly. For instance, if you have `public static class MyConsts` in your project with `public static bool IsDebug { get { ... } }` in it, you can simply do:

  ```
  if (MyConsts.IsDebug)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

  in your form file.

---

A few remarks which may help you through your migration from Java to C#:

1. Your application is not a WPF application. It's Windows Forms. Comparing WPF to Windows Forms is more or less like comparing Swing to AWT; WPF is newer and much more powerful, but you may not necessarily need this power, in which case Windows Forms is a perfectly valid choice. One major benefit of WPF for any application is data binding.
2. C# has [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx). Use them. This is similar to `getSomething` and `setSomething` in Java, but provides a more concise syntax. **Never access fields directly.**
3. C# coding standards slightly differ from Java's; for instance, methods start with an uppercase letter. You can [find them on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx), but you may also consider using [StyleCop](https://stylecop.codeplex.com/) which checks whether your code matches the style rules.
4. If you want your application to behave differently in debug mode than in release mode, you can simply use the [`#if DEBUG`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2104128/240613). If you want to provide more verbose logging in debug mode, .NET Framework's logging already differentiates between debug and release mode, so you don't need to implement anything at code level.